# Seek rows with incorrect dates in historic data

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I had a table that is an historic log, recently I fixed a bug that was writing in that table an incorrect date, the dates should be correlatives, but in some cases there was a date that wasn't it, so much older than the previous date.

How can I get all the rows that aren't correlatives for each entity_id? In the example below I should get the rows 5 and 10.
The table has millions of rows and thousand of differents entities. I was thinking to compare the results of ordering by date and id but that is a lot of manual work.

```
| id     | entity_id   | time_stamp    |
|--------|-------------|---------------|
| 1      | 7           | 2019-01-22    |
| 2      | 9           | 2019-01-05    |
| 3      | 6           | 2019-03-14    |
| 4      | 9           | 2019-04-20    |
| 5      | 6           | 2015-10-04    | WRONG
| 6      | 9           | 2019-07-15    |
| 7      | 3           | 2019-07-04    |
| 8      | 7           | 2019-06-01    |
| 9      | 6           | 2019-11-04    |
| 10     | 7           | 2019-03-04    | WRONG
```

Are there any function to compare the previous date by the entity id? I'm completely lost here, not sure how to clean the data. The database is MYSQL by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `lag()`; the idea is to order records by `id` within groups having the same `entity_id`, and then to filter on records where the current timestamp is smaller than the previous one:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*, lag(time_stamp) over(partition by entity_id order by id) lag_time_stamp
    from mytable t
) t
where time_stamp < lag_time_stamp
```

In earlier versions, one option is to use a correlated subquery to get the previous timestamp:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where time_stamp < (
    select time_stamp 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.entity_id = t.entity_id and t1.id < t.id
    order by id desc
    limit 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM sourcetable s1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM sourcetable s2
               WHERE s1.id < s2.id
                 AND s1.entity_id = s2.entity_id
                 AND s1.time_stamp > s2.time_stamp )
```

The index by `(entity_id, id, time_stamp)` or `(entity_id, time_stamp, id)` will increase the performance.